# New to powershell, I have a csv file with 3 column attempting to extract value of the first column base on a value of the 3rd column

Tags: powershell, csv

```
users$ = import-csv 'C:\windows\temp\names.csv'

foreach{user$ in Users$){
write-host users.fname | where {$users.value -eq 1
}
```

Content of file...

```
fname   lname   value
Mike    smith   1
Beba    johnson 1
Wayne   devon   1
South   martinez    1
Doug    Garcia  2
Doug    faulk   2
Michael underwood   3
Nate    Ray 3
Mamu    lawrence    3
Brian   Simpson 4
Jiggy   Washington  4
Mano    navid   4
```

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
$users = import-csv 'C:\windows\temp\names.csv'

foreach ($user in $users){
  if ($user.value -ge 1){Write-host $user.fname}
}
```

you could also do something similar to this so its already in a PSObject ready for export

```
$users | where {$_.value -ge "1" -and $_.fname -ne $null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a closing brace after the "eq 1" - ie }

Answer (score 0):

```
#solution 1####################################################################
import-csv 'C:\windows\temp\names.csv' | where Value -eq 1 | select fname 

#solution 1 short version
ipcsv 'C:\windows\temp\names.csv' | ? Value -eq 1 | select fname 

#solution 2#####################################################################
import-csv 'C:\windows\temp\names.csv' | foreach { if ($_.Value -eq 1) {$_.fname} }

#solution 2 short version
ipcsv 'C:\windows\temp\names.csv' | % { if ($_.Value -eq 1) {$_.fname} }
```